# Append a List to another list

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my first array.

```
 data = [
  {
    "id": 8651,
    "value": "Abdominal pain"
  },
  {
    "id": 8646,
    "value": "Chest pain"
  },
  {
    "id": 8642,
    "value": "Cough"
  }
]
```

This is my second array.

```
{
  "symptoms": [
    "N",
    "N",
    "Y"
  ]
}
```

These two arrays need to be combined to get this.

```
[
  {
    "id": 8651,
    "value": "Abdominal pain",
    "result": "N"
  },
  {
    "id": 8646,
    "value": "Chest pain",
    "result": "N"
  },
  {
    "id": 8642,
    "value": "Cough",
    "result": "Y"
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this. tried with reduce & concat, I didn't got the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this with `map` function:

```
var data = [
  {
    "id": 8651,
    "value": "Abdominal pain"
  },
  {
    "id": 8646,
    "value": "Chest pain"
  },
  {
    "id": 8642,
    "value": "Cough"
  }
]

var symptoms = {
  "symptoms": [
    "N",
    "N",
    "Y"
  ]
}

const mapFunction = (dataItem, index) => ({...dataItem, "result": symptoms.symptoms[index]});
const mappedResult = data.map(mapFunction)

console.log(mappedResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

```
for(let i = 0; i<this.data.length; i++) {
    this.data[i]["result"] = this.symptoms.symptoms[i];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **map** operator for this..

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
let newArr = [];

data.map((item, index) => {
  newArr.push(data[index]);
  newArr[index]['result'] = symptoms[index];
});
```